# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 button with a tooltip. When clicking the button the tooltip shows and then fades out. When clicking a 2nd time the tooltip flickers and does not nicely fade out. But when clicking the 3rd time the behavior is like expected again.

**Update**: The below code works fine with Bootstrap 3.0.0, but not with Bootstrap 3.3.7.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom'
});

function setTooltip(node, message) {
  node.attr('data-original-title', message)
    .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(node) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    node.tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var node = $(this);
  var msg = node.attr('data-title');
  setTooltip(node, msg);
  hideTooltip(node);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-title='Tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip'>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `trigger: 'manual'` so you can control how the tooltip is shown or hidden.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  trigger: 'manual',
  placement: 'bottom'
});

function showTooltip(node) {
  node.tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(node) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    node.tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var node = $(this);
  showTooltip(node);
  hideTooltip(node);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-title="Tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you with a solution

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var node = $(this);
  var msg = node.attr('data-title');
  node.attr('data-original-title', msg)
    .tooltip('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    node.tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
});

$('.btn').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-placement='bottom' data-title='Tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' data-trigger='manual'>Click me</button>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: @FastSnail What bug you got ??

Comment: @FastSnail Bug fixed.